# Style property only from classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, styles

Is it possible to get certain css style property computer only from classes, without taking into account possible run-time manipulation?

For example:

```
.container{
}

.container .item {
}

.container.inactive .item {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Somewhere in javascript opacity of item changes to 1 via, say, $('.item').css('opacity',1) but then I need to know what was certain item's opacity without run-time modifications, based on only its classes. Structure of css is just an example and shouldn't be taken into account to check for opacity.

Is it possible?

Comment: So you dont want overwrite your styles from javascript. is it right?

Comment: What do mean about runtime manipulation?

Comment: Why do you need to find this out? I ask because if you want it to revert back to normal you would just take off the opacity you set via jQuery.

Comment: If it's just a few elements, you could always store the original state, but I know that could get unwieldy pretty quickly.

Comment: @Ruddy Yes, I need to remove any changes which were made via .css('opacity',xxx) during run-time, but I am not sure how to do it. My guess that, say, .css('opacity','') could clear opacity completely, but what if it was, say, 0.5 in class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I understand what you want.

Take a look at this fiddle I made. The `div` already has `opacity: 0.6;` then when we click the `div` it will make the div `opacity: 0.2;` (via jQuery). To remove this we can simply remove the `style` from `div`.

**HTML:**

```
<div>Click Me</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var count = 0;
$("div").click(function () {
    if (count == 1) {

        $(this).removeAttr("style");
        count = 0;
    } else {

        $(this).css("opacity", "0.2");
        count = 1;
    }
});
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3NApa/)

This is a simple demo to show you how it works. Using `.css` will put the `css` inline, it will not change the style sheet.

---

Learn more about `.css` [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: I need only to reset opacity, buy .css('opacity',"") do the trick. At least in chrome and firefox, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can know the value of CSS attributes(say opacity) using jQuery like this:

```
var color = $(".item").css( "opacity" );
```

Or

```
var color = $(".container > .inactive > .item").css( "opacity" );
```

Comment: > Structure of css is just an example and shouldn't be taken into account to check for opacity.

Comment: There could be hundreds of such elements, without clear ID and something. Probably I could use some item.data('formerOpacity',item.css('opacity')) for each element on document .ready and then do item.css('opacity',item.data('formerOpacity') when needed, but that's a little bit overkill in my opinion. I'd like to find more efficient solution. Especially, that original opacity could be changed in some earlier .ready initializations

Comment: If I understand your need correctly, you want to calculate value the the css attribute.

Comment: Something lik this: <div id="q" style="background: yellow; line-height: expression(document.getElementById('q').offsetHeight/2+'px');">
    Lorem ipsum fiddly boing bum dfg dsfgasdf fg asdfas.
    Lorem ipsum fiddly boing bum dfg dsfgasdf fg asdfas.
    Lorem ipsum fiddly boing bum dfg dsfgasdf fg asdfas.
</div>